# .NET 3.5 Hosting in IE11/Windows 8.1, not able to communicate with web service

Tags: web-services, hosting, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I have an application where I host a .NET 3.5 Windows Forms control in Internet explorer to provide access to a scanner. The control works fine in IE7 through IE10 and IE11, but it is not workingin IE11 on Windows 8.1 (desktop mode).

The PC in question has both .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 and .NET 4.0/4.5 installed and enabled, the site has been added to the trusted zone, CASPOL permissions have been set the same as they are on the PC's running Win7 and EnableIEHosting has been set to 1 at both 32 and 64bit levels on the PC.

Debugging locally indicates that the problem lies in calling a web service method  which never seems to return and never seems to actually run either. All I am left with is a locked IE11 that has to be closed from task manager.

I have diagnosed that it is actually the constructor of a Web service client that fails to return. It is a simple generated client class and as such simply calls the base constructor ; unfortunately, it is failing within the call to the base class.

As previously stated, this has worked without problem from IE7 through IE10 on Windows XP through Windows 8.0 and I am absolutely certain that the CASPOL configurations etc. have been set correctly.

Is anybody aware of any other problems or new configuration requirements when hosting .NET Windows Forms controls in IE11?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your machines are up to date, but I've just had an IE 11 and .net 4 related issue (and have read about lots more) caused by being behind on .net updates. I'm not entirely sure if this applies to your situation, but the problem was .net failing to identify IE 11 as an IE browser, which naturally could cause various problems.

[This is the hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us) that sorted the problem I was having, and is talked more by Scott Hanselman [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx).

Hope this is of some use for you, or other passers by struggling with .net 4 and IE 11 issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got breakthrough.

As we cannot deploy service config in web application that hosts windows form control.
I created constructor in code itself and it worked absolutely fine.

Following is code sample.

```
    Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding
    Dim endPoint As New EndpointAddress("http://SERVERNAME/<WEBSITE>/YOURSERVICE.svc")
    Dim obj As New TestWCFService.TestWCFServiceClient(binding, endPoint)
```

Hope this works for you too.